# read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I' followed a tutorial with reactJS and a I have some problems with "map".
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
class GoalList extends Component{
componentDidMount(){
    goalRef.on('value', snap=>{
        let goals=[];
        snap.forEach(goal =>{
            const {email, title}=goal.val();
            goals.push({email, title});
        });
        console.log('goals', goals);
        this.props.setGoals(goals);
    })
}
render(){
    console.log('this.props.goals', this.props.goals);
    return(
        <div>
            {this.props.goals.map((goal, index) => {
                return (
                    <GoalItem key={index} goal={goal} />
                )})}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: suspect this.props.goals is not yet defined, or is null,  
try changing: to check for undef/null:   this.props.goals && this.props.goals.map

Comment: `goalRef.on('value', snap=>{` This looks very much async. So when your render method runs first time likely `this.props.goals` is not defined yet. If you are using redux set goals to be empty array inside initial state  or check if `this.props.goals` is a thing directly inside `render`

Comment: Make sure that "this.props.goals" is an array. Probably it is not yet defined at that point ('undefined'). You can provide a check before, like: if (this.props.goals instanceof Array) { this.props.goals.map()... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @developer said in his comment your issue is that your code throws an error because `this.props.goals` is not defined at the time and you can't do a `map` over `undefined`.

You can easily fix this by providing a default :

```
render(){
    const { goals = [] } = this.props;
    return(
        <div>
            {goals.map((goal, index) => {
                return (
                    <GoalItem key={index} goal={goal} />
                )})}
        </div>
    )
}
```

You can also do this using `defaultProps` :

```
static defaultProps = {
  goals: []
}
```